# Target specific div in jQuery

Tags: jquery, accordion, slidetoggle

I am trying to make my code more efficient. So I am trying to use the same line of jQuery to create a toggle.

I have got this working for 1 item on my page.

The problem I have is when clicking the second item that is to slide down, It is sliding the first element down.

I have created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y3mKA/). to demo my issue.

and my jQuery is as follows....

```
// Accordion Related....
    $('h3.accordion-header').click(function()
    {
        $('.accordion').children().eq(1).slideToggle(function ()
        {
            $('h3.accordion-header').toggleClass('active', $(this).is(':visible'));
        });

        return false; // Prevent Default Click..

    })
```

I am wondering how do I target that specific class of accordion not the first on the page. If its at all possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `$(".accordion")`you are selecting all accordion elements, not just the one inside the element you clicked. The same happens when setting the active class.

This code will work:

```
// Accordion Related....
    $('h3.accordion-header').click(function()
    {
        var currentClicked = $(this);
        currentClicked.parent().find(".row").slideToggle(function ()
        {
            currentClicked.toggleClass('active', $(this).is(':visible'));
        });

        return false; // Prevent Default Click..

    })
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Y3mKA/4/

Comment: Thanks @Dark Ashelin this works a treat. Was looking into something in the middle of the previous answer and yours. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

use `this` reference and `closest()`..

```
// Accordion Related....
$('h3.accordion-header').click(function () {
   $(this).closest('.accordion').children().eq(1).slideToggle(function () {
 //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-----here 
     $(this).toggleClass('active', $(this).is(':visible'));
   });


   return false; // Prevent Default Click..

})
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Y3mKA/5/)

or easiest would be usign `next()`..(if you are sure the elements is always next to the `h3` element)

```
 $('h3.accordion-header').click(function () {
   $(this).next().slideToggle(function () {
      $(this).toggleClass('active', $(this).is(':visible'));
   });
     return false; // Prevent Default Click..
  });
```

[fiddle using next()](http://jsfiddle.net/Y3mKA/6/)

Answer (score 1):

The code could capture the event at the accordion level.  Then the other selections can be scoped more easily.

```
$(".accordion").on("click", ".accordion-header", function()
{
    var that = this;
    $(".row", $(this).parents(".accordion")).slideToggle(function ()
    {
        $(that).toggleClass('active',  $(this).is(':visible'));
    });

    return false; // Prevent Default Click..
});
```

**Js Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/Y3mKA/8/